# Manually setting log ticks in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting wind speed as a contour plot, with latitude as the x co-ordinate and pressure as the y axis.

I want the y axis as a log scale, and this works as shown below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoSGN.png

How do I specify where the y ticks are, i.e at the moment it plots a tick at 1000mb, 100mb etc. How would I specify it so it plots ticks at say 1000,900,700,500,200mb etc.

I tried making an array of numbers and putting this in the ytick code but it didn't work!

Many thanks in advance.

PS Ideally it'd have a similar log tick scale as this here;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJCxB.jpg

Here is my code;

```
    from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

myfile = '/home/ubuntu/Python-Postburn_Tools/out.nc'
Import = Dataset(myfile, mode='r') 

print Import.variables       #Display contents of NC File (i.e list variables)
print Import.variables['ua'] #Lists shape of variable e.g(time, lev, lat, lon)

lons = Import.variables['lon'][:]    #Longitude
lats = Import.variables['lat'][:]    #Latitude
time = Import.variables['time'][:]   #Time
height = Import.variables['lev'][:]  #Levels
wind = Import.variables['ua'][:]
#relax = Import.variables['var154'][:]
temp = Import.variables['ta'][:]

display = np.average(wind[12:131,:,:,0],axis=0)       #Use this to plot a variable

                                                         #Visual changes
uscale = [-40,-35,-30,-25,-20,-15,-10,-5,0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40]  

CS = plt.contourf(lats,height,display,uscale,cmap=plt.cm.jet)
cbar = plt.colorbar(CS)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Temperature (C)')

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.yscale('log', nonposy='clip')
plt.xticks(np.round((np.arange(-90, 91, 30)), 2))
plt.xlim(xmin=-90)


plt.xlabel('Latitude')        
plt.ylabel('Pressure (hPa)')    
plt.title('Year 2-11 control Temp - TRelax (C)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the moment it's difficult to help you as we don't know how your code works.

Comment: Sorry, I'll just upload my code now!

Comment: You can use `yticks`, but you'll also have to set the tick labels: `plt.yticks([1000,900,700,500,200]); plt.gca().set_yticklabels([1000,900,700,500,200])`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot.. I would mark this as the best answer but I'm unaware of how to do so (newbie)!